# How can I check whether a given string contains another substring more than once?

Tags: string, kotlin, substring

How can I check whether a given string contains another substring more than once?

```
fun isFieldRepeated(jsonIn: String, field:String): Boolean { 
  var count: Int = 0; 
  while (jsonIn.indexOf(field) > -1) { 
       jsonIn = jsonIn.substring(jsonIn.indexOf(field)+field.length(),jsonIn.length()); 
       count++;  
  } 
  if(count>1) 
   return true; 
  return false; 
 }
```

Comment: You could check if firstIndexOf is equal to lastIndexOf. If it isn't the field is repeated.

Comment: No, sir. I want check whether string is contained more than one time. Not if it only contains one.

Comment: Probably refering to my old comment - I realized what was wrong after reading again more carefully. See my answer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify it to

```kotlin
fun isFieldRepeated(jsonIn: String, field:String): Boolean =
  jsonIn.firstIndexOf(field) != jsonIn.lastIndexOf(field)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun isFieldRepeated(jsonIn: String, field: String): Boolean {
  return jsonIn.windowed(field.length) { it == field }.count { it } > 1
}
```

Or as an extension function:

```
fun String.isFieldRepeated(field: String) = windowed(field.length) { it == field }.count { it } > 1
```

... to be used for example like this:

```
println("abcdefghcdij".isFieldRepeated("cd"))
```